# replacement of JCS2N65F TRANSISTOR MOSFET REGULATOR FOR TV HAIER

Tags: replacement

What is the Replacement of JCS2N65F TRANSISTOR MOSFET REGULATOR FOR AFTRON TV HAIER we are in Afghanistan I attempt to much to find but I am failed?[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you choose a component for a design, you should consider: -

```
The desired circuit functionality and
The desired circuit performance and
The data sheets of candidate components
```

When you replace that component with another, you should consider: -

```
The desired circuit functionality and
The desired circuit performance and
The data sheets of candidate component
```

So, with no visible circuit to study, it means no clear understanding of: -

```
The desired circuit functionality and
The desired circuit performance
```

And no clear idea of what component can be chosen

Answer (score 2):

These are obsolete with better parts available. You found the photo and this site. Next find a similar old colour TV to get similar part for high voltage flyback  generator

Another way to watch FIFA is to use an LCD with Composite TV out to VGA adapter to PC monitor.

It is called a fast N channel 600V rated Power FET 4 Ohms typ.

http://www.datasheet8.cn/download.php?id=924604

Greetings from Canada.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [datasheet](http://www.jingheng.cn/uploadfiles/files/20170412083728_6301.pdf) for a similar part number from Jinheng. "F" is for the fullpack overmoulded TO-220 case you have. Take care if a subsitute lacks the insulation you'll have worse problems than you do now.

Chances are it's originally made by other companies and you can find a more-or-less exact replacement with a similar part number.

If you don't mind waiting for a dubious Aliexpress source, they're currently offered with your exact part number at 10 pieces for CAD 4.08 including shipping from China to Canada. They want USD 0.40 more to ship to Afghanistan.